# super().save() returns nothing in django

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to overwrite `save()` method in my forms.py ,i'm trying to prevent creating duplicated objects , and if the object exists only update some fields of the model this is my models.py

```
class Item(models.Model):
    item = models.ForeignKey(Product,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.IntegerField()
```

my forms.py

```
class ItemForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Item
        fields = ['item','quantity']

    def save(self,*args,**kwargs):
        if self.instance.item:
            Item.objects.filter(item__name=self.instance.item).update(
               quantity=F('quantity') + self.instance.quantity)  
        else:
            super().save(*args,**kwargs)
```

my views.py

```
def addNewItem(request):
   form = ItemForm()
   if request.method == 'POST':
       form = ItemForm(request.POST)
       if form.is_valid():           
            form.save()

   return render(request,'temp/add_item.html',{'form':form})
```

lets say i have entered this data : `item = abc , quantity = 100` for the next time if i entered `abc` it prevent from creating another object with the same name , but when i try to enter a new object it returns nothing ! does it is a wrong way to call `super().save(*args,**kwargs)` !

Comment: How do you know `super.save()` returns nothing?  You aren't capturing the return value.

Comment: i used `print('something')` in the else condition

Comment: Printing something in the else part only shows whether or not your code ended up there: not what save does or does not return.

Comment: and so if it was worked at least it creates a new object , when i enter a new data

Comment: If you are override a method, you should *always* return the `super().save()` result (unless you really know better; but then you should return the equivalent type at least). Please read more thoroughly through the Django documentation to see how this is done there: there are enough examples of overriding the `save()` method.

Comment: @9769953 what i did wrong !?

Comment: i did exactly what you trying to say but still doesnt work @9769953

Comment: Consider making the `item` field `unique`, and catch the exception when saving the modelform. Then you don't need to override `save`. But if your ForeignKey is *required* to be unique, then a OneToOneField is the better option.

Comment: you are probably catching the data wrong, if you are trying to access the model instance, you capture it from your view then using cbv get_kwargs, pass in the data you want.

Comment: @9769953 how to build the catch exception please for OneToOneField